# Error resolving plugin, You must specify a URL for a Maven repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I have a problem after clone the repo, during first gredle built of my springboot project  an error appear

```
Error resolving plugin [id: 'some plugin', version: 'plugin version']
> You must specify a URL for a Maven repository.
```

in my bulid.gradle file just written like this

```
plugins {
  id "some plugin" version "${PluginVersion}"
}
```

Do i have to do a setting. Im using Intelli J in this project. Thanks in Advance

Comment: "some plugin" doesn't sound like a name for a real plugin :)

Comment: @BjørnVester you never gonna believe this,  but this is work for me, I open my intelliJ idea from terminal then build succeeded. If I open directly by clicking the application icon it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify url in repositories

```
 repositories {
   maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/release" }
   maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
 }
```

You have to specify the repository URL according to your need.

Check [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify maven repository where your plugins are located in `settings.gradle` e.g.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'urlToRepository'
        }
        maven {
            url 'anotherUrlToRepository'
        }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```